# The current path, **/POST, didn’t match any of these

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have a login page that has an auth form, 2 values, after validation, redirect it with these 2 parameters, but i get an error, what did i miss?

The Views

```
def LoginPage(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        ordernr = request.POST.get('bestellnummer')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        try:
            ...."validation shopify api"
        else:
            return redirect(f'login/{ordernr}/{email}/')
```

the urls app

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.LoginPage, name="login"),
    path('login/<str:pk>/<str:dk>/', views.OrderPage, name="order"),
]
```

the from

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div>
        <form action="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
            <div>
                <label for="bestellnummer">Ihre Bestellnummer</label>
                <input type="text" name="bestellnummer" id="bestellnummer" placeholder="Ihre Bestellnummer...">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="email">Ihre Bestell E-Mail</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Ihre E-Mail...">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>

    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Page not found (404) your text
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/POST?csrfmiddlewaretoken=token123&bestellnummer=1337&email=somefiller@mail.com
Using the URLconf defined in retourenportal.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
login/ [name='login']
login/str:pk/str:email/ [name='order']
The current path, login/POST, didn’t match any of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote `action` twice instead of `method`:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  …
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html file should look like this:

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div>
    <form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
        <div>
            <label for="bestellnummer">Ihre Bestellnummer</label>
            <input type="text" name="bestellnummer" id="bestellnummer" placeholder="Ihre Bestellnummer...">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="email">Ihre Bestell E-Mail</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Ihre E-Mail...">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>

</div>
{% endblock content %}
```